# MYSQL - Combine multiple result sets in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have the following stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS active_locations;

CREATE PROCEDURE active_locations()

BEGIN

DECLARE y INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE LOC VARCHAR(200);

WHILE y < 6 DO

SELECT CONCAT('SELECT table_sample.LOC', GROUP_CONCAT(y), '_Status'
                        ' FROM table_sample') INTO @LOC;

SET y = y + 1;

PREPARE stmt FROM @LOC;
EXECUTE stmt;

END WHILE;

END//
```

However, when I call this procedure in Navicat, I'm getting multiple result sets for each iteration of y (so in this case, 5). I've tried inserting the results into a temporary table but can only get the results where y = 1. I'm not familiar with stored procedures but I think that for each loop of y, MySQL is executing the 
`SELECT table_sample.LOC', GROUP_CONCAT(y), '_Status' ' FROM table_sample` in a separate window.

Is there anyway to combine these columns into one table but while still displaying the data column by column?

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag since this is about MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Each EXECUTE results in a new result set. So if you want one result set, you must do EXECUTE only once.

You could create a single SELECT that is comprised of six sub-SELECT's glued together with UNION ALL:

```
SET @LOC = '';
WHILE y < 6 DO
    SET @LOC = CONCAT(@LOC, ' SELECT table_sample.LOC', y, '_Status'
                        ' FROM table_sample UNION ALL');
    SET y = y + 1;
END WHILE;

/* Now we have one extra UNION ALL at the end, so remove it. */
SET @LOC = LEFT(@LOC, LENGTH(@LOC)-LENGTH('UNION ALL'));

PREPARE stmt FROM @LOC;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

By the way, this would be a lot simpler if you stored your data in First Normal Form, by creating a child table, so the six `LOCn_Status` columns could be stored as one column over six rows.

Comment: Hi Bill, I've tried your suggestion but I am still only getting one column in the EXECUTE statement. What do you mean by storing my data in First Normal Form?

Comment: Can't tell what you want. Please edit your question above and show an example of what you want the result to be.

Comment: Hi Bill, I took a look at your query again and I see that all my column are being displayed together now because of the UNION. Is it possible to have them displayed by column within the same EXECUTE statement?

Comment: If you want the columns to be displayed by column, then why are you forming a dynamic SQL query in the first place? Why not simply `SELECT * FROM table_sample`? No WHILE loop, no PREPARE, no EXECUTE.

Comment: Because the table I am selecting from contains more than just these columns and there are more than 5 columns that I need to select (the code posted is just an example). I will take your first suggestion and try to store my data in First Normal Form in the first place.

Comment: All right, `SELECT *` was just an example, I don't usually do that in production code. You could alternatively just name the columns you want.